# Javascript timer not stopping

Tags: javascript, php, counter

The following script counts down but it won't stop counting when it reaches the end time. 
When it reaches zero, it start again from 60:00 to 0 (another hour). 
When i skip the part

```
$time = str_replace(' ', 'T', $db[time]);
```

and do it like this:

```
var end = new Date('<?=$db[time]?>');
```

The counter is stopping correctly, but then the counter wont work at IE or Firefox only in Chrome.

Anyone know how to stop this counter:S Thanx!

```
$db[time] = Timestamp field in the database (2013-10-03 11:32:39)
```

The Script:

```
$time = str_replace(' ', 'T', $db[time]);
```

Java script

```
<script>
var end = new Date('<?=$time?>');
var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;
var _day = _hour * 24;
var timer;

function showRemaining() {
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;
    if (distance < 0) {

        clearInterval(timer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'ITS NOW TIME!</font><BR><BR>';                
        return;
    }
    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);


    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = '<font color="orange">' + minutes + ':';
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += '<font color="orange">' + seconds + ' minutes</font>';
}

timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
 </script>
```

Comment: Check this on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/agAvEbU/1/edit This code is working fine. The problem must be somewhere else

Comment: See Katana314's comment on the fact that you use `innerHTML` with malformed HTML. Each and every single assignment to innerHTML should contain welformed HTML, otherwise the browser will change your HTML so that it will be "welformed" (or malformed with regards to your intentions) afterwards

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use

`var countInterval = setInterval(function() { countdown(secondsRemaining); },1000)` instead.

This way you won't have to play around with Date or Time objects. Just keep a count inside `countdown()` and `clearInterval(countInterval)` once  you reach `60`.

Comment: You are really suggesting to replace the function reference with a string that will have to be eval()-ed before execution?

Comment: I'm suggesting to calculate the seconds remaining on the backend where it's browser independent, and do a simple setInterval on the front-end.

Comment: But it's best practice to use a function reference as the first parameter to `setInterval` ... which the OP already did. But you replaced it with a string, which is considered bad practice

Comment: Good insight -- there is no need to compare dates. A function reference is preferred over a code string, but the approach is sound.

Comment: @devnull69 Yes, after a quick google, I agree with you. I updated my example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little suspicious of your innerHTML usage. Where is this script located in the HTML? I have a feeling it's getting re-evaluated after setting innerHTML. You could test the theory by putting a `console.log("Started!")` statement next to `setInterval`.

Also, look here:

```
document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'ITS NOW TIME!</font><BR><BR>';
```

You're "setting" (replacing) the innerHTML of an element so it will contain: text, and then a close-font tag. That might mess up your DOM. Finally, you shouldn't be setting innerHTML twice in two lines - set it *once* in a function, perhaps based on a variable.

(To clarify: Using innerHTML on its own isn't the worst thing - but with malformed HTML, or by adjusting an element too high in the heirarchy, it can have unintended effects)